# Getting an array of certain objects within an object

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get an array of all "form" objects within a large "masterFormObject" object. Is this the cleanest way to do so, or is there a better way I can check if the form objects themselves are not undefined directly and check both the applicant and account portion of this form object without having two separate blocks of undefined checks / forEach loops?

```
vm.getAllForms = function (type) {

  var allForms = [];
  var accountForms = [];
  var applicantForms = [];

  if (undefined != vm.masterFormObject) {
    if (undefined != vm.masterFormObject.payload) {
      if (undefined != vm.masterFormObject.payload.accounts) {
        vm.masterFormObject.payload.accounts.forEach(function (account) {
          if (undefined != account.Forms) {

            account.Forms.forEach(function (Form) {

              allForms.push(Form);
              accountForms.push(Form);

            });
          }
        });
      }

      if (undefined != vm.masterFormObject.payload.accounts) {
        vm.masterFormObject.payload.applicants.forEach(function (applicant) {
          if (undefined != applicant.Forms) {
            applicant.Forms.forEach(function (Form) {
              allForms.push(Form);
              applicantForms.push(Form);
            });
          }
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to code review. I hope you get some good answers.

Answer (score 1):

Your nested "ifs" make the code very hard to read.  I would think about changing your approach to something like

```
if (undefined === vm.masterFormObject) {
    console.log('Some error message.');
    return;
}
if (undefined === vm.masterFormObject.payload) {
    console.log('Some other message');
    return;
}
// and so on

// or if inside a loop
if (undefined === account.Forms) {
    console.log('Some error message.');
    // continue to next iteration
    continue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question,

I think you wanted to check for `vm.masterFormObject.payload.applicants` not being `undefined` right before you do a forEach on it?

I would chain the `undefined` checks and use a falsey/truthy approach:

```
  if ( vm.masterFormObject && 
       vm.masterFormObject.payload && 
       vm.masterFormObject.payload.accounts) {
    //Do the thing
  }
```

Furthermore, since both `accounts` and `applicants` have data in `.forms` I would use a function to extract that.

Also, you have written your own version basically of `Array.concat()`, I would just use `concat` to keep it simple.

All in all that gives something like

```
vm.getAllForms = function (type) {

  var allForms = [],
      accountForms = [];
      applicantForms = [];

  function extractForms( records ){
    var forms = [];
    records.forEach(function (record) {
      if( record.Forms ){
        forms = forms.concat( record.Forms ); 
      }
    }
    return forms;
  }

  if ( vm.masterFormObject && 
       vm.masterFormObject.payload ){
    var payload = vm.masterFormObject.payload;
    if( payload.accounts ) {
      accountForms = extractForms( payload.accounts );
    }
    if( payload.applicants ) {
      applicantForms = extractForms(payload.applicants );
    }
  }
  allForms = accountForms.concat( applicantForms );

}
```

If this was a personal project I would have used this for `extractForms`:

```
  function extractForms( records ){
    var forms = [];
    records.forEach(function (record) {
        forms = forms.concat( record.Forms || [] ); 
    }
    return forms;
  }
```

It basically replaces record.Forms with an empty array if the value is undefined, it just looks more elegant to me, but probably would not pass most corporate code reviews.